# How to set the visibility GONE after the download was successful, and visibility still VISIBLE if download was unsuccessful?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am making a studymaterial app, where i want to add a functionality where - when a user download a particular chapter from recyclerview and after the successful download of that item the Download button visivity should make GONE of that item at that time.

I have implemented a method to do thisd but it only works when user finish the activity and come back again on that activity then the download button automatic not showing, but i want to implement at that point of time when user download something.

`Here is my DownloadHandler.kt class`

```
package com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.downloadHandler

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.app.ProgressDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.widget.Toast
import com.downloader.*
import com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.DownloadedFiles
import java.io.File
import com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.R


class DownloadHandler {
    lateinit var alertDialog: AlertDialog.Builder
    lateinit var failed: AlertDialog.Builder
    var progressDialog: ProgressDialog? = null
    var fileDestination: File? = null
    var down: Boolean = false


    fun downloadFile(url: String?, fileName: String, context: Context, filePath: File): Boolean {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog(context)
        progressDialog!!.setMessage("Downloading....")
        progressDialog!!.setCancelable(false)
        progressDialog!!.max = 100
        progressDialog!!.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER)
        progressDialog!!.show()
        alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        alertDialog.setTitle("Downloaded successfully")
        alertDialog.setMessage("$fileName is downloaded successfully")
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.check)
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(
            "Open"
        ) { _, i ->
            val intent = Intent(context, DownloadedFiles::class.java)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
        failed = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        failed.setTitle("Downloading failed")
        failed.setMessage("Your file is not downloaded successfully")
        failed.setIcon(R.drawable.failed)

        PRDownloader.download(url, filePath.path, fileName)
            .build()
            .setOnStartOrResumeListener { }
            .setOnPauseListener { }
            .setOnCancelListener { }
            .setOnProgressListener { progress ->
                val per = progress.currentBytes * 100 / progress.totalBytes
                progressDialog!!.setMessage("Downloading : $per %")
            }
            .start(object : OnDownloadListener {
                override fun onDownloadComplete() {
                    down = true
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Download completed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    progressDialog!!.dismiss()
                    alertDialog.show()

                }

                override fun onError(error: Error) {
                    down = false
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    failed.show()
                    progressDialog!!.dismiss()
                }
            })
        return down
    }


}
```

`Adapter Class`

```
package com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.adapters

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.Interface.OnPDFSelectListener
import com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.Interface.PDFDownloadListner
import com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.PDFActivity
import com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.R
import com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.models.StudyMaterials
import java.io.File
import java.lang.String
import kotlin.Int

class MaterialsAdapter(
    var context: Context,
    var arrayList: List<StudyMaterials>,
    var listener: PDFDownloadListner,
    var pdfSelectListener: OnPDFSelectListener,
    var folderLocations: File
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MaterialsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.custom_materials, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.subjectHead.text = arrayList[position].chNo
        holder.subjectName.text = arrayList[position].Title

        val file =
            File(
                "$folderLocations/" + String.valueOf(
                    "Ch-" + arrayList[position].chNo + ". "
                            + arrayList[position].Title + " [twoRoot2]" + ".pdf"
                )
            )

        if (file.exists()) {
            holder.downloadBtn.visibility = View.GONE
        }


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if (file.exists()) {
                pdfSelectListener.onPDFSelected(file)
            } else {
                val intent = Intent(holder.itemView.context, PDFActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("link", arrayList[position].Link)
                intent.putExtra("flag", "y")
                intent.putExtra("title", arrayList[position].Title)
                intent.putExtra("chNo", arrayList[position].chNo)
                it.context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }

        holder.downloadBtn.setOnClickListener {

          val downloaded =  listener.onDownload(
                arrayList[position].Link,
                String.valueOf("Ch-" + arrayList[position].chNo)
                    .toString() + ". " + arrayList[position].Title
            )



        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return arrayList.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val subjectName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.subjectName);
        val subjectHead = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.subjectHead);
        val downloadBtn = itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.downloadBtn);
    }


}
```

`Activity Class`

```
package com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert

import android.app.ProgressDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.Interface.OnPDFSelectListener
import com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.Interface.PDFDownloadListner
import com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.adapters.MaterialsAdapter
import com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.application.MyApplicationClass
import com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.downloadHandler.DownloadHandler
import com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.viewModels.MainViewModel
import com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.viewModels.MainViewModelFactory
import com.tworoot2.result10th_12th.Internetconnection.NetworkUtils
import java.io.File

class MaterialsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), PDFDownloadListner, OnPDFSelectListener {

    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
    lateinit var file: File
    lateinit var fileDestination: File
    lateinit var downloadHandler: DownloadHandler


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_materials)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)


        // download listener
        downloadHandler = DownloadHandler()


        file = File(getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + "/" + "Class")

        fileDestination = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Class")

        if (!fileDestination.exists()) {
            fileDestination.mkdirs()
        }

        if (!NetworkUtils.isInternetAvailable(this@MaterialsActivity)) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MaterialsActivity, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }

        val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading....")
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false)
        progressDialog.show()


        val medium = intent.getStringExtra("medium")

        val repository = (application as MyApplicationClass).materialsRepo

        mainViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this, MainViewModelFactory(repository))[MainViewModel::class.java]



        if (medium.equals("h")) {
            mainViewModel.hisHinLiveData.observe(this) {

                this@MaterialsActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
                    val adapter =
                        MaterialsAdapter(
                            this@MaterialsActivity, it!!.studyMaterialCS,
                            this, this, file
                        )
                    progressDialog.dismiss()
                    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

                })

            }
        } else if (medium.equals("e")) {
            mainViewModel.hisEngLiveData.observe(this) {

                this@MaterialsActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
                    val adapter =
                        MaterialsAdapter(
                            this@MaterialsActivity, it!!.studyMaterialCS,
                            this, this, file
                        )
                    progressDialog.dismiss()
                    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

                })
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this@MaterialsActivity, "Everything is invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }


    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                finish()
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onDownload(url: String?, title: String?) {
        val time = System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
        val shortTime = time.substring(8, 12)
        val fileName = "$title [twoRoot2]"

//        downloadFile(url, fileName  + ".pdf");


//        downloadFile(url, fileName  + ".pdf");
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Downloading....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val downloaded =
            downloadHandler.downloadFile(url, "$fileName.pdf", this@MaterialsActivity, file)
//        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "D...." + downloaded, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }

    override fun onPDFSelected(file: File?) {
        val intent = Intent(this@MaterialsActivity, PDFActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("path", file!!.absolutePath)
        intent.putExtra("flag", "n")
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onDelete(file: File?, position: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun inExternalApp(file: File?, context: Context?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

}
```

> Repository Class

```
package com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.repository

import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.api.MaterialsService
import com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.models.MaterialsElist
import com.tworoot2.class9thhistoryncert.models.MaterialsList
import com.tworoot2.result10th_12th.Internetconnection.NetworkUtils

class MaterialsRepo(private val service: MaterialsService, private val context: Context) {

    private val hisHinMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<MaterialsList>()
    private val hisEngMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<MaterialsList>()

    val hisHinLiveData: LiveData<MaterialsList>
        get() = hisHinMutableLiveData

    val hisEngLiveData: LiveData<MaterialsList>
        get() = hisEngMutableLiveData

    suspend fun getHisHindi() {
        if (NetworkUtils.isInternetAvailable(context)) {
            val result = service.getHistoryHindiFromAPI()
            if (result.body() != null) {
                hisHinMutableLiveData.postValue(result.body())
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("InternetError", "No Internet Connection")

        }
    }

    suspend fun getHisEnglish() {
        if (NetworkUtils.isInternetAvailable(context)) {
            val result = service.getHistoryEnglishFromAPI()
            if (result.body() != null) {
                hisEngMutableLiveData.postValue(result.body())
            }
        }else{
            Log.e("InternetError", "No Internet Connection")

        }
    }

}
```

[[Screen Shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKpSY.jpg)]

[[Screen Shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0yjb.jpg)]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use LiveData to handle realtime update UI for your case. After download thread run completed, let observer call update item in recyclerview.
Hope it help!

Comment: I have implemented the LiveData, but it is not updating the data in realtime, I have updated the code and added repository class in above file